# Only diff single type of change from a node app?

Tags: reactjs, git, diff, git-diff

I have a view in a node React app that I want to either highlight added OR removed lines, but not both at the same time.

Is there an npm module to diff for ONLY added lines OR removed lines.

Something like the git `--diff-filter=[ACDM]` flag

```
Select only files that are

* A Added
* C Copied
* D Deleted
* M Modified
* [omitted]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [git-diff](https://github.com/danday74/git-diff) package allows you to pass in an [options-object](https://github.com/danday74/git-diff#options-object).

You can pass in the `--diff-filter=[ACDM]` flag that you want via [this object](https://github.com/danday74/git-diff#flags-string--null-).

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you know if there's a similar package (send options ansd return unified diff string) that can run in the browser?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. However, you could always do this on the server side and return the diff to the browser